# Is this exponetial operator a contraction?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have an operator $ T(f(x)) = e^{-|f|}$  from $C[0,1]$ to itself, and want to find whether it's a contraction or not. First i tried to find a counterexample but did not succed. Then I started with $ \| Tf - Tg \| $
where I expand each operator as $$ T(h) = e^{-|h|} = 1 -|h| + \frac{|h|^2}{2!} - \frac{|h|^3}{3!}+...$$

then I obtained

$$ \| Tf - Tg \| = \|\bigg(1 -|f| + \frac{|h|^2}{2!} - \frac{|h|^3}{3!}+... \bigg) -\bigg( 1 -|g| + \frac{|g|^2}{2!} - \frac{|g|^3}{3!}+...\bigg)  \| 
\\
= \|\bigg(|g|-|f| \bigg)+\bigg(\frac{|f|^2}{2!} - \frac{|f|^3}{3!}+...\bigg) -\bigg(\frac{|g|^2}{2!} - \frac{|g|^3}{3!}+...\bigg)  \|
$$

then I got stuck.

Comment: Group the $g$ and $f$ together. Under sup norm, what inequalities do you know?

Comment: Well, the triangle inequality does hold yes

Comment: maybe you could use Lagrange theorem?

Comment: Use that $t\mapsto e^{-|t|}$ is Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}$, which can be seen by computing its derivative.

Comment: @IAmNoOne Group them as I did in my post or in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

let $h=f-g$, suppose that T is a contraction
meaning $\forall f,g \in C[0,1] ,||T(f)-T(g)||\leq \lambda ||f-g||$

$
||T(-h)-1||\leq \lambda ||h||\times ||T(f)||$ we chose f such that $||T(f)||=1 ( f(x)=x )$

we have and this is crucial $
||T(-h)-1|| \geq T(-||h||)-1 \geq ||h||  $

therefore 
$ \lambda ||h|| \geq ||h||$

i. e, $ \lambda \geq 1$

so $T$ is not a contraction.